# Image button focus Issue

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-selector

I have one image button in my screen.If i click the button by using touch screen, image focus and pressed everything is works properly.If the same thing i have handled with the D'pad button,it will go the hover state and then it moved to the next screen,after i come back to the previous screen still it is retaining the hover state instead of default state.For this how to overcome?

my code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/cc_btn_vehicleinfo_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/cc_btn_vehicleinfo_hover"
          android:state_focused="true" 
          /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/cc_btn_vehicleinfo_default"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: @CommonsWare can you review this question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Styled Button](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/) it will surely help you. There are lots examples please search on INTERNET.

eg:style

```
<style name="Widget.Button" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_dot</item>
</style>
```

you can use your `selector` instead of `red_dot`

red_dot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"  >

    <solid android:color="#f00"/>
    <size android:width="55dip"
        android:height="55dip"/>
</shape>
```

Button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        style="@style/Widget.Button"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: selector is working fine ..please understand my question,i am getting the problem while using d'pad.